# Reading a file in React after it has been built

Tags: reactjs

I am reading a file into my React component like this:

```
let SVN_VERSION;

try{
  SVN_VERSION = require("./svnversion.txt");
}catch(e){}

...

async componentDidMount(){

    if(!SVN_VERSION) return;

    const res = await fetch(SVN_VERSION);
    const svnVersion = await res.text();
    this.setState({svnVersion})
}
```

This works fine on my local machine. When I change the content of the file, the component gets updated.

However, after I built the project with `npm run build` it doesn't get updated anymore. It just takes the content at built time.

I was wondering how I could make it so that it dynamically reads the content of the file?

Comment: This is not possible as the file gets compiled into the build so it can be served through a webserver. The easiest way to serve dynamic content is probably to create an API and load it through XHTTPRequests. EDIT: You might get it to update after you reload the page but definitely not hot reload.

Comment: update after reload would be fine, how would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created project with create-react-app and the component still updated dynamically with the content in the file after I built. Can you post your webpack config, your build folder structure or your full code?

Below is my build folder

[image: My build folder]

Comment: That did the trick, I just have to update that svnverison file in the media folder. THANKS !